# PHP trader extension cdl functions not working

Tags: php, phptrader

I have enabled PHP trader extension, and I am using its functions like trader_rsi, trader_macd etc without any problem, but none of the cdl (candle stick) functions are working, for example hammer:

```
$opens = [1, 1.1, 1.2];
$highs = [1.5, 1.6, 1.7];
$lows = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7];
$closes = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4];
$hammerPatterns = trader_cdlhammer($opens, $highs, $lows, $closes);

if ($hammerPatterns === false) {
    dd("trader_cdlhammer failed with error code: " . trader_errno());
    // trader_cdlhammer failed with error code: 2
} else {
    print_r($hammerPatterns);
}
```

The weird thing is all other functions are working as mentioned, like rsi, macd, sma, atr, adx, but none of the cdl functions are working, and they all outputing error code 2 from trader_errno(). and there is nowhere i can find about this error number, unless this one which has no explanation about codes:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-errno.php

how is this possible for all trader functions to work but not cdl functions?
BTW, i am using PHP 8.2.15

Comment: i tested your code on 8.1 and it works smooth. I think something went wrong during the installation process try to purge and reinstall the extension and debug installation log